# What is the technical term for the time taken to see the final image on an IP security camera's screen?

Tags: terminology

What is the technical term for the time taken to see the final image on an IP camera's screen?

Is it dependent on some parameter which I can look for?

Actually this website has listed various parameters, but I can't make out whether above is listed out there or not?

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps7307/prod_models_comparison.html#~hd_cameras

Comment: You should mention in your question that you are talking about IP cameras.

Comment: @eWolf Done it. Now, any helps?

Comment: I don't think security cameras are on topic.

Comment: @mattdm It is mentioned in the FAQ/rules?

Comment: Is it _photography_? The FAQ doesn't list everything that's off-topic, because that'd be impossible. I'm just applying common sense here.

Comment: @mattdm I had seen discussions about the camera models here, so I thought camera is a camera, be it simply digital or for security. After all, all I was asking for was technical info. ;D ;D

Comment: But the site isn't all-about-cameras-for-any-purpose.stackexchange.com. After all, videography and cinema questions are not on topic. I think it's really important to keep the focus on photography. In this case, since the issue has a lot to do with computer power and computer networking, it seems clearly out of the gray area. Now, if you can explain that you're using the security camera for an avant-garde portrait project, then it'd be back on the other side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word you are looking for is **[Latency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_%28engineering%29)**.

> Latency is a measure of time delay experienced in a system, the precise definition of which depends on the system and the time being measured. Latencies may have different meaning in different contexts.
>   [...]
>   **Satellite transmission**
>   This is best illustrated when a newsreader in a studio talks to a reporter half way around the world. The signal travels from the newsreader via communication satellite situated in geosynchronous orbit to the reporter and then goes all the way back to geosynchronous orbit and then to the studio, resulting in a journey of over one hundred thousand kilometers . This time lag is easily noticeable. Even though the signal travels at the speed of light, it still requires about half a second to travel that distance (not including the much smaller latencies inside the communications equipment).

**[Lag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lag)** is also an acceptable substitute, though it is considerably more informal.

> Lag is a common word meaning to fail to keep up or to fall behind. In real-time applications, the term is used when the application fails to respond in a timely fashion to inputs.
>   [...]
>   The term lag is often also used as a synonym for communication latency. This can be misleading because there can be other causes for the symptom.

---

It's worth noting that the video latency of IP cameras is not entirely due to the camera itself. Depending on the intervening network, network latency can actually produce the majority of the delay in the signal.